# Creating a button for scientific calculator

Tags: android, android-layout, calculator, android-gridlayout

..[image: consider this image of my calc]

As shown in the figure i have to create buttons with two functions. For example, in the bottom first row the "0" has another function called "Rnd" and "." has functions "Ran# RanInt".

I have taken this up as a project and I am stuck - I can't get the buttons, and the name above the button as shown in figure to be in a correct alignment.

Also, I am not sure this is the correct method, I have used `GridLayout` as shown in code, I used a `LinearLayout` inside of `GridLayout` for the buttons and they seem to fit - but I can't make the text to be placed above the buttons as shown in figure.

The font file can be downloaded from [**here**](http://edu.casio.com/education/fontset/) ... download **casio fx-es plus series**. I have renamed the file ES-03 as `casiofont.ttf` in my program.

screen shot  [image]

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="space to show enabled functions"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/webView2" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/webView2"

        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></WebView>

        <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:rowCount="9"
        android:columnCount="6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webView2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:weightSum="5"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/webView2"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/gridlayout">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rnd"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/rnd"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    android:layout_row="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ran_ranint"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/ran_ranint"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    android:layout_row="0" />

                <com.example.girikarnal.engineringcalc.CalculatorButtonTextView
                    android:id="@+id/pi_e1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/pi_e"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_row="0" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pi_e2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/e"
                    android:layout_weight="0.78"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="0" />
                <com.example.girikarnal.engineringcalc.CalculatorButtonTextView
                    android:layout_width="41dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/drg_ans"
                    android:text="@string/dgr_ans"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.80" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0">


        <com.example.girikarnal.engineringcalc.CalculatorButtonButton
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:text="@string/zero_Rnd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <com.example.girikarnal.engineringcalc.CalculatorButtonButton
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            android:text="@string/dot_or_ran"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <com.example.girikarnal.engineringcalc.CalculatorButtonButton
            android:id="@+id/multiple_of_ten"
            android:text="@string/multiple_of_ten_or_pi_e"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <com.example.girikarnal.engineringcalc.CalculatorButtonButton
            android:id="@+id/ans"
            android:text="@string/ans_or_DRG"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <com.example.girikarnal.engineringcalc.CalculatorButtonButton
            android:id="@+id/equals"
            android:text="@string/equals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:layout_row="1" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </GridLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

CalculatorButton

```
public class CalculatorButtonButton extends Button {
    public CalculatorButtonButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CalculatorButtonButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CalculatorButtonButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CalculatorButtonButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/casiofont.ttf");
//        String s="tf";
//        SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(s);
//        spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

CalculatorTextView

```
public class CalculatorButtonTextView extends TextView {

    // Constructors
    public CalculatorButtonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
    public CalculatorButtonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public CalculatorButtonTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    // This class requires casiofont.ttf to be in the assets/fonts folder
    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/casiofont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am making a scientific calculator similar to casio 991es, I have problem in designing the buttons.I can add a button but I need to add a small text above that button that tells the user an alternate function of the button. Pls s the image i have added as a link. I tried and searched but i can not the UI to look like in the image so I am asking for help.

Comment: I dont understand why i am getting negative votes for this q..

Comment: because you didn't provide an image of what you got as a result of your attempts, you didn't specify your attempts (for example showing the XML for the layout which gives you the errorenous result), and *it is not clear what you want to get, what you got, and what you did to get what you got.* As such, we cannot tell you what you did wrong, and we cannot help. As such, this is a *bad question*, as indicated by http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have provided the image click on the "calc"  the third word in my question,it vl take you to the link where the image is displayed, I cant upload a image directly as i am a new member. I tried and got a little of the solution will complete it and upload the code.

Comment: I tried with gridview and table layout, it is not working for me.i have put up the image link clearly.... please help me

Comment: https://www.google.hu/search?site=&source=hp&ei=6zAhVdirLZLeasfDgJAP&q=gridlayout+example+android&oq=gridlay&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.1.0.41j0l4.1370.1865.0.2813.8.5.0.1.1.0.492.1398.0j1j3j0j1.5.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-hp..4.4.791.3.kGibmBsAupw

Comment: -@EpicPandaForce I tried in gridview and uploaded the code pls suggest improvements.

Comment: can you show a picture of what you get after executing your code? Errors, or problem with layout? A screen capture would be nice.

Comment: -@EpicPandaForce i have added the screen shot...

Comment: Why are you creating a `WebView`?

Comment: i can use javascript in webview , it vl be helpful... pls give some thoughts on layout.

Comment: No, you seriously shouldn't go the WebView/Javascript route.

Comment: `GridLayout` does not work the way you would expect it would. You should create custom layout for a button with the `TextView` and a `Button`. I would reccomend to instantiate those dynamically.

Comment: -@Lamorak can you please explain more... any links if possible

Comment: -@EpicPandaForce it was given that in javascript calculations can be done easily by using eval functions so i just kept it there.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a custom view.
Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:text="btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CalcBtn class

```
public class CalcBtn extends LinearLayout {
    public CalcBtn(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CalcBtn(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CalcBtn(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.calc_btn, this);
    }
}
```

And then use it in your layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.example.example.CalcBtn
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.example.example.CalcBtn
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.example.example.CalcBtn
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.example.example.CalcBtn
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm slightly confused, why extend from `LinearLayout` instead of `Button`? or is it so can you can have multiple UI components (textview AND a button) within the given View?

Comment: -@EpicPandaForce thank you for encouraging this question... there are not much projects and codes available in the scientific calc category.. I want to complete this and upload it to git hub it will be useful.

Comment: -@EpicPandaForce this is the link where webview and javascript is used .. he has taken the example of a simple calculator.. pls have a look at this link and tell your suggestions.... http://www.androiddom.com/2011/04/creating-android-calculator-tutorial.html

Comment: -@EpicPandaForce so we can have textview and button within single view and make it perfectly aligned, yes

Comment: No need to go all the way defining custom `LinearLayout`s here, just `<include layout="@layout/calc_btn">`  in the parent layout. (cf. [Android developer doc](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html))

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not clear how exactly you want to lay out your buttons, but firstly you got several things wrong in your usage of `GridLayout`:

- the row and column counts seem wrong (don't you have 2 rows and 5 columns ?)
- there's no need for a `LinearLayout` within the `GridLayout` ; each child of `GridLayout` will be assigned a cell in the grid, so you can lay text and button views directly under the grid layout (cf. example below)

Additionally:

- most likely the `GridLayout` height should be `wrap_content` given the rest of the layout
- no need to specify a column span of 1, that's the default (that's not even a *span* actually...)
- no need to specify children layout widths and heights (they're not taken into account in `GridLayout`)
- no *need* to specify children column and row indexes, they'll be added to the grid in the order they are declared
- no need to specify the row numbers either, it can be inferred from the columns number and the number of children

So, you could declare your grid with something like this:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:columnCount="5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text2"/>
    <!-- ... etc add you remaining 3 labels here -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/textButton1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/textButton2"/>
    <!-- ... etc add you remaining 3 buttons here -->

</GridLayout>
```

*But* if I understand correctly you want to create equally sized columns and rows (and maybe stretch or shrink them ?), and `GridLayout` (from my experience) can be very tricky to adapt to these use cases (if you want to go down that road, try using `Space`s rather than fiddling with row / column and elements attributes). `TableLayout` works way better for this though. You'd write something like this instead:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:shrinkColumns="*">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text2"/>
        <!-- ... etc add you remaining 3 labels here -->
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="@string/textButton1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="@string/textButton2"/>
        <!-- ... etc add you remaining 3 buttons here -->
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Or, if you want your columns to be equally sized and take up all the width available to the `TableLayout`, using weights:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <!-- ... etc add you remaining 3 labels here -->
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="@string/textButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="@string/textButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <!-- ... etc add you remaining 3 buttons here -->
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

You could also use nested `LinearLayout`s (a horizontal one with 5 nested vertical ones or vice-versa), this is basically what `TableLayout` does (`TableLayout` and `TableRow` *are* `LinearLayout`s).

By the way these examples are with "plain" text views and buttons, but you can of course use your Casio-font-enabled custom ones in place it won't make any difference.

So although `GridLayout` is usable and should consume less system resources than `TableLayout`, the latter may be easier to configure to match your desired layout.

For details I recommend checking the [`GridLayout` guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) and the [`TableLayout` one](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html).

Comment: thank you for taking up interest in my question, To be more clear about what I want to accomplish and remove any confusion I want my layout to be exactly like the image of the calculator[fx-991es plus] I have put.                            I used tablelayout first but there was a problem as in some places i have to use two textview in the same column and on searching i got to know that the tablerow doent allow that.

Comment: Gridview is complicated , I will make the corrections you have suggested but do correct me if I am wrong about the tablerow so I can fix on a way.

Comment: `TableLayout` doesn't support column spanning like `GridLayout` does, that's true, but if you want to put 2 `TextView`s in one cell for example you can wrap them in a layout (let's say `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` for example) and put that layout into the cell. It makes it easier to configure, but you start to deepen the view hierarchy, true. You could also use `GridLayout` without much trouble if you fix the size of the text views and buttons. If you want the layout to be reactive though, it _may_ be tricky to achieve properly.

Comment: Yes it has to be reactive because it has shift and alpha buttons , when i press these buttons the buttons represent the function which is written in textview above the buttons .

Comment: Sorry I meant responsive, meaning whether you want to give cells a fixed size or not. I'd recommend you to try and fix your originals layouts (grid or table) as per my answer, and if you encounter other problems (e.g. one view is not centered in its cell), open a new question about that _specific_ problem and it'll be easier for people to help you with it. If anything remains unclear as to how `GridLayout` and `TableLayout` work though I'd be happy to update my answer.